# How do I install ubuntu on a laptop that has had its windows operating system removed?

Tags: system-installation

As a charity we have been donated an HP laptop. Unfortunately it has been cleaned to such an extent that the original VISTA operating system has gone. I have created a USB drive containing the ubuntu linux system, and tried to use this as the boot. However, after a short time the boot hangs. Is there any way I can install linux on this laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Check out:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest

Try booting with a cd/dvd and make sure that the boot priority of your devices is set correctly.

If you need step by step assistance with the installation of ubuntu, please checkout the "Installation & Upgrades" of the ubuntu forums at : http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=333